# extract ppt from office word using OpenXml format through c#

Tags: visual-studio-2005

I want to extract a flash object from a word doc using OpenXml.I have done it other way round but it is not working as, if there are many flash objects then the processing time got hampered and henceforth i think openxml is more suitable>please someone help me in doing the same .I am coding in c#

Comment: So are you starting with a DOC or a DOCX file?

Comment: Just wanted to follow up to see if the below is getting you any closer to what you need

Answer (score 1):

Use this: [Standalone tool for extracting embedded Office Open XML objects from files](http://embeddedoleextractor.codeplex.com/)